# Magento 2.4.3 Upgrade from 2.3.0 showing iframe for Online payment

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.4, magento-upgrade, credit-card

I have upgraded Magento 2.3.0 to Magento 2.4.3, everything is working perfectly but when selecting CCAvenue online payment on payment page, one iFrame is showing below to enter credit card information with the "Payment Information" header before proceeding which was not coming before.

Without adding the details I can't move forward.

Attaching screenshot below
[image]

How to remove this iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

This information is required to pay with new versions. Maybe this iframe is caused by your payment module fee calling.

You can check it in Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods. In this go to the method you are using and change the payment type (if the module supports it)

Note: In case this module does not support it, you are required to enter the card information before redirecting to the bank's payment page.